# How can I run an "upsert" on PostgreSQL when using a joined-table-inheritance with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

The title says it all, and here is an example reproducing the error I get (TB below). PostgreSQL is require due to the usage of `on_conflict_do_update` construct:

```
from sqlalchemy import (Column, DateTime, ForeignKeyConstraint, Integer,
                        String, create_engine, func)
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_table"
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "parent",
        "polymorphic_on": "polymorphic_type",
    }
    parent_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))
    polymorphic_type = Column(String, nullable=False)
    updated = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())


class Child(Parent):
    __tablename__ = "child_table"
    __mapper_args__ = {"polymorphic_identity": "child"}
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(  # type: ignore
            ["parent_id"],
            ["parent_table.parent_id"],
            onupdate="CASCADE",
            ondelete="CASCADE",
        ),
    )
    parent_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_column = Column(String(50))


engine = create_engine("postgresql://", echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

sess = Session()
c1 = Child(name="foo", child_column="bar")
sess.add(c1)
sess.commit()
sess.close()


sess = Session()
insert_stmt = insert(Child)
insert_stmt = insert_stmt.values([
    {"name": "newname", "child_column": "newchildcol"},
    {"name": "newname2", "child_column": "newchildcol2"},
    {"name": "foo", "child_column": "updatedcol"},
])
insert_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=[
        Parent.parent_id,
    ],
    set_={
        "name": insert_stmt.excluded.name,
        "child_column": insert_stmt.excluded.child_column,
        "updated": func.now(),
    },
)
session.execute(insert_stmt)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 210, in __getattr__
    return self._data[key]
KeyError: 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upsert_with_jti.py", line 60, in <module>
    "name": insert_stmt.excluded.name,
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 212, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)
AttributeError: name
```

After a lot of digging around, I went as far as injecting a debugger into the place where SA gets the "excluded" columns by doing the following:

```
...
def bp(*a, **kw):
    from pdb import set_trace; set_trace()  # XXX debugger
...
insert_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
...
    set_={
        "name": bp(insert_stmt.excluded),
        ...
    },
)
```

In the debugger I get the following:

```
(Pdb) pp dir(a[0])
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__get__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__self__',
 '__self_class__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__thisclass__',
 'child_table_child_column',
 'child_table_parent_id',
 'parent_table_name',
 'parent_table_parent_id',
 'parent_table_polymorphic_type',
 'parent_table_updated']
```

It's evident that the columns had to be aliased for this operation. I thought this was the issue. But after substituting `name` with `parent_table_name` in the "excluded" columns, I still get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upsert_with_jti.py", line 66, in <module>
    sess.execute(insert_stmt)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1292, in execute
    clause, params or {}
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1014, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    else None,
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 476, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 482, in _compiler
    return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 590, in __init__
    Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 319, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 350, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 95, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2428, in visit_insert
    self, insert_stmt, crud.ISINSERT, **kw
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/crud.py", line 64, in _setup_crud_params
    return _get_crud_params(compiler, stmt, **kw)
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/crud.py", line 167, in _get_crud_params
    kw,
  File "/home/users/malbert/tmp/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/crud.py", line 367, in _scan_cols
    and c is not stmt.table._autoincrement_column
AttributeError: 'Join' object has no attribute '_autoincrement_column'
```

This leads me to believe that running an "upsert" on a joined-table-inheritance is not supported by SA? What is a better way to do this?

Note that I am currently working this for performance issues. I have a fairly large data set which suffers from the many "selects" currently caused by "bulk" inserts which happen regularly. I want to leverage either the "bulk" operations of SA, or (maybe sufficiently performant) an insert statement with many values (as shown in the example above). I *have* a naive version of the code running, but it's getting slow as the number of inserted rows has increased substantially recently.

I would like to benefit from the "upsert" nature as well, but it's currently not trivial. The parent table contains a surrogate primary key, and each child table has another natural key. Unfortunately, the surrogate key is unavailable on the input data. For example, in the example above, the surrogate key would be the `parent_id` and the natural child-key would be `child_column`. Specifically something like this:

```
Device (parent-table)
---------------------
id: uuid (PK/surrogate)
scope: text (part of natural key with child)
hostname: text (part of natural key with child)
ip: text (part of natural key with child)

Component (child-table)
-----------------------
id: uuid (fk with parent)
component-id: text (part of natural key)
```

So the duplication needs to be detected on "component-id" in conjunction with the scope/hostname/ip triple because the same component-id can be used on different devices.

There are other child tables which have other NKs but the overall issue is the same.

Comment: Were you able to solve this finally?

Comment: unfortunately not :(